# Using the PodSixNet library with Python, I am having trouble using Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

So I am using [PodSixNet](http://mccormick.cx/projects/PodSixNet/) to have server-client interaction. It works great, but when I try to add Tkinter, I get a maximum recursion depth in assyncore.

Here is my client, the server works flawlessly:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from sys import stdin, exit
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter

from PodSixNet.Connection import connection, ConnectionListener

# This example uses Python threads to manage async input from sys.stdin.
# This is so that I can receive input from the console whilst running the server.
# Don't ever do this - it's slow and ugly. (I'm doing it for simplicity's sake)
from thread import *
class App:
        def __init__(self, master, connection):
            self.connection = connection
            self.frame = Frame(master)
            self.frame.pack()
            self.connection.Send({"action":"nickname","nickname":"test"})
class Client(ConnectionListener):
    global players
    players = []
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        root = Tk()
        root.title("CHAT")
        app = App(root, connection)
        start_new_thread(root.mainloop, ())
        print "Enter your nickname:",
        nick = raw_input()
        self.Connect((host, port))
        connection.Send({"action": "nickname", "nickname": nick})
        # launch our threaded input loop
        t = start_new_thread(self.InputLoop, ())
    
    def Loop(self):
        connection.Pump()
        self.Pump()
    
    def InputLoop(self):
        global players
        
        # horrid threaded input loop
        # continually reads from stdin and sends whatever is typed to the server
        while 1:
            msg = raw_input()
            if msg.startswith("/"):
                cmd = msg[1:]
                if cmd.lower().startswith("pm"):
                    to = cmd[3:].split(" ", 1)[0]
                    msg = cmd[3:].split(" ", 1)[1]
                    if to in players:
                        connection.Send({"action": "PM", "to": to, "message":msg})
                    else:
                        print "That person is not online!"
                        continue
                elif cmd.lower().startswith("name"):
                    newName = cmd[5:]
                    connection.Send({"action":"nickname","nickname":newName})
            else:
                connection.Send({"action": "message", "message": msg})
    
    #######################################
    ### Network event/message callbacks ###
    #######################################
    
    def Network_players(self, data):
        global players
        #Recieved list of players.
        players = data['players']
    
    def Network_message(self, data):
        #Got a message.
        print data['from'] + ": " + data['message']\
        
    def Network_serverMessage(self, data):
        msg = data['message']
        print "Server:",msg
    def Network_PMrecieve(self, data):
        msg = data['message']
        of = data['from']
        print "PM from " + of + ": " + msg
    def Network_PMsuccess(self, data):
        success = data['success']
        if success == True:
            print "PM successfully sent!"
        else:
            print "Error, recipient may not be online."
        
    # built in stuff
    def Network_connected(self, data):
        print "You are now connected to the server"
    
    def Network_error(self, data):
        print 'error:', data['error'][1]
        connection.Close()
    
    def Network_disconnected(self, data):
        print 'Server disconnected'
        exit()

c = Client("localhost", 12345)
while 1:
    c.Loop()
    sleep(0.001)
```

It only gives errors when I try to use connection.Send from anywhere else than the Client class

I heard it might be that Tkinter is not thread safe? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access Tkinter widgets from more than one thread. You are creating the root window in one thread but running the event loop in another.

Comment: So do I thread it all to one thread? And can I access a function from another thread to add something to a tkinter widget?

Comment: To add something to a widget from another thread, you'll have to put something on a queue, the pull it off of the queue in the main thread.  See http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm

Comment: Instead of doing that for every type of widget, could I just use that for the root?